# The maven package phase

Tags: maven

I am new to maven and will be very happy for an explanation on the maven package phase. I have a maven project named com-theta-gesture with three java classes. One of the classes has the main method in it. When I run the mvn package command , the target folder is created. Below is the structure of the target folder

```
  target/
        |
        classes/
        |
        maven-archive/
        |
        generated-sources/
        |
        testclasses/
        |
        surefire_report/
        |
        com-theta-gesture-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

within the classes folder are the three compiled java classes of the application. My question is if I am to run this application, do I have to run the com-theta-gesture-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar executable jar or do I have to run the main class in the classes folder. Because when I try the following command

```
C:\Users\FAISAL\Desktop\disaster\com-bbox-gesture\target>java com-bbox-gesture-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

I get the following the error

```
Error: Could not find or load main class com-bbox-gesture-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Hope to find an explanation.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use the assembly plugin if you're just building a standalone JAR file.

Instead, you can simply configure the maven-jar-plugin, which is already being used in your project, as follows:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      ...
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
      ...
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

You won't need the `addClasspath` if it's a standalone JAR with no dependencies.

The snippet above can be found by going to the documentation for [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), and clicking [Creating an Executable JAR File](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#Make) in the left navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Google for "maven self executable jar" will give you the answer

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

In short, a JAR is not executable automatically.  You need to put the Main Class information in the MANIFEST file.  The quoted link describe the normal way in Maven to setup such information.

Answer (score 0):

The jar is not an executable jar by default as Adrian Shum explains.

If however you just want to run the jar but without creating an executable jar you can use the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/).

This is a small pom file with the inclusion of the `exec-maven-plugin`:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.acne</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</name>

    <properties>
        <mainClass>com.acne.App</mainClass>
        <argument/>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    <arguments>
                        <argument>${argument}</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

With this pom you can do the following:

```
mvn package exec:java
```

And your program will be packaged then executed.

With the defined properties you can easily change the main class and add an argument:

```
mvn exec:java -DmainClass=com.acne.Calculator -Dargument=100
```

Comment: thanks maba that is a explanation, but I actually want to create an executable jar. Will probably try the other suggestions